# TypeError: $("#search-form").jqTransform is not a function

Tags: jquery, plugins, jqtransform

i will use jqTransform (plugin of jquery);
but when page loaded show error on firebug :

```
TypeError: $("#search-form").jqTransform is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

...'#search-form').jqTransform({imgPath: "http://localhost/bankemelk/includes/img/"...
```

this is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#search-form').jqTransform({imgPath: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>includes/img/"});
        $('#search-form1').jqTransform({imgPath: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>includes/img/"});
        console.log();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: are you including `jqTransform` in your page?

Comment: Show your HTML code where you are linking to the js script containing the plugin

Comment: yes including successfull. but show this error

Comment: Hm, without the html to check it's hard to say, but it seems like, or you're including `jqTransform` first and then `jQuery`, you have a conflict with `$`, or you're are not including some script.

Comment: by the way, this code works on simple html but in this way, when i use this script with codeigniter do not work!!!

Comment: please help me. this code do not work

Answer (score 0):

you can try with $("#search-form").jqTransform();
it should automatically load the right image
but it seems that you aren't including it as you should.
Show your code...

Anyway, if I may, here is a replacement for jqtransform that I've started 7 months ago.
http://www.pkoretic.net/csTransPie/

I've made it exactly because of all the problems jqtransform had.
It started as jqtransform improvement, now is something else and better I hope...